# Slowdown when playing games in i3 X11 but not gnome X11

Tags: gnome, nvidia, i3, games

I have a problem that I find very difficult to reproduce. I have Manjaro with i3. It runs on a laptop with an RTX 3060.

Whenever I play a game, eventually, the game and i3 will eventually freeze up either for a second or two or sometimes permanently. When I switch to a different terminal with ctrl alt f6 and kill the game, sometimes i3 works again sometimes I have to reboot the system.

I have also tried the same on gnome X11, it works without any problem, meaning the problem has to be with x11.

I checked Xorg.0.log and the nvidia log but I can't find any problems. Is there a way I can diagnose this issue? Is there any way I can try to consistently reproduce it?

EDIT:

VSync seems to make it appear less frequently

Comment: Make sure to disable compositors if you run any in i3.

Comment: I think getting rid of compton fixed it. I accidentally still had it in my old i3 config. Still wish there was a way to use Direct Rendering Manager and optimus together, so autorandr would work

Comment: Compositors (and in particular desktop effects they allow) are almost always the cause of such slowdowns and draggy screen actions, so first step to debug is always to disable any desktop effects and ideally the  compositor. I stopped using those ages ago, they just add resource consumption and do nothing of positive value for your desktop imo. Obviously not possible with wayland. Though desktop effects to me should always be disabled no matter what. That includes stuff like transluscent windows etc, you'll find your experience much peppier without that stuff.

Comment: yeah, but neither optimus nor DRM are compositors. DRM is needed for autorandr and other stuff to work correctly (I also find it makes the who system a bit less buggy) and optimus is needed to conserve battery life by using the onboard iGPU for any application that isn't a video game

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the slowdowns by enabling Nvidias Direct Rendering Manager:
[Direct Rendering Manager not working with RTX3060 on propriatery NVIDIA Driver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/746174/direct-rendering-manager-not-working-with-rtx3060-on-propriatery-nvidia-driver)

Although now the whole System runs exculsively on the Nvidia GPU, which has a large impact on battery life. So you should consider disabling it when you plan on using your laptop away from wall power.