# Direct Rendering Manager not working with RTX3060 on propriatery NVIDIA Driver

Tags: nvidia, drm

I have tried to enable the DRM by setting this kernel parameter in Manjaro i3:

```
nvidia_drm.modeset=1
```

but afterwards the system refused to start lightDM because of the following Xorg error:

```
failed to create screen resources
```

After some digging I have found the following message in the kernel logs that mentions a failing noveau driver, even though I haven't installed the nouveau driver. So can someone make sense of this?

```
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timer: stalled at ffffffffffffffff
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: WARNING: CPU: 14 PID: 746 at drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nvkm/subdev/mmu/vmmtu102.c:43 tu102_vmm_flush+0x165/0x170 [nouveau]
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: Modules linked in: ntfs3 uas usb_storage ccm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg snd_ctl_led snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_sof_probes snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio qrtr squas>
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  polyval_generic ecdh_generic gf128mul videobuf2_vmalloc snd_hda_intel mac80211 fat ghash_clmulni_intel i915 nouveau libarc4 snd_intel_dspcfg videobuf2_memops sha512_ssse3 snd_intel_sdw_acpi videobuf2_v4l2 aesni_intel snd_hda_codec videobuf2_com>
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: CPU: 14 PID: 746 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G        W          6.1.1-1-MANJARO #1 58eeef856bad441bca33a8abb39f91301fd24d8d
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: Hardware name: HP Victus by HP Laptop 16-d0xxx/88F8, BIOS F.22 11/28/2022
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: RIP: 0010:tu102_vmm_flush+0x165/0x170 [nouveau]
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: Code: 8b 40 10 48 8b 78 10 48 8b 5f 50 48 85 db 75 03 48 8b 1f e8 6d 09 a9 c8 48 89 da 48 c7 c7 74 be 47 c1 48 89 c6 e8 c6 64 e8 c8 <0f> 0b eb a5 e8 c2 28 ee c8 66 90 f3 0f 1e fa 0f 1f 44 00 00 ff 74
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb64ac179b778 EFLAGS: 00010282
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: WARNING: CPU: 14 PID: 746 at drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nvkm/subdev/mmu/vmmtu102.c:43 tu102_vmm_flush+0x165/0x170 [nouveau]
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: Modules linked in: ntfs3 uas usb_storage ccm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg snd_ctl_led snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_sof_probes snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio qrtr squas>
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  polyval_generic ecdh_generic gf128mul videobuf2_vmalloc snd_hda_intel mac80211 fat ghash_clmulni_intel i915 nouveau libarc4 snd_intel_dspcfg videobuf2_memops sha512_ssse3 snd_intel_sdw_acpi videobuf2_v4l2 aesni_intel snd_hda_codec videobuf2_com>
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: CPU: 14 PID: 746 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G        W          6.1.1-1-MANJARO #1 58eeef856bad441bca33a8abb39f91301fd24d8d
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: Hardware name: HP Victus by HP Laptop 16-d0xxx/88F8, BIOS F.22 11/28/2022
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: RIP: 0010:tu102_vmm_flush+0x165/0x170 [nouveau]
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: Code: 8b 40 10 48 8b 78 10 48 8b 5f 50 48 85 db 75 03 48 8b 1f e8 6d 09 a9 c8 48 89 da 48 c7 c7 74 be 47 c1 48 89 c6 e8 c6 64 e8 c8 <0f> 0b eb a5 e8 c2 28 ee c8 66 90 f3 0f 1e fa 0f 1f 44 00 00 ff 74
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb64ac179b778 EFLAGS: 00010282
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff98e542c9d160 RCX: 0000000000000027
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: RDX: ffff98eccfba1668 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: ffff98eccfba1660
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: RBP: ffff98e560866400 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: ffffb64ac179b600
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: R10: 0000000000000003 R11: ffffffff8b4b7110 R12: 0000000005000001
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: R13: ffff98e560866400 R14: ffff98e5634136c0 R15: 0000000000000000
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: FS:  00007f6a3d5a2980(0000) GS:ffff98eccfb80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: CR2: 00007f6a34044060 CR3: 000000012143a004 CR4: 0000000000f70ee0
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: PKRU: 55555554
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: Call Trace:
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  <TASK>
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  nvkm_vmm_unref_pdes+0xeb/0x1f0 [nouveau b94536815bcbee6c07bf0305391ef14c5a1db60e]
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  nvkm_vmm_unref_pdes+0x182/0x1f0 [nouveau b94536815bcbee6c07bf0305391ef14c5a1db60e]
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  nvkm_vmm_unref_pdes+0x182/0x1f0 [nouveau b94536815bcbee6c07bf0305391ef14c5a1db60e]
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  nvkm_vmm_unref_pdes+0x182/0x1f0 [nouveau b94536815bcbee6c07bf0305391ef14c5a1db60e]
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  nvkm_vmm_unref_ptes+0x18c/0x250 [nouveau b94536815bcbee6c07bf0305391ef14c5a1db60e]
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  nvkm_vmm_iter.constprop.0+0x2a5/0x890 [nouveau b94536815bcbee6c07bf0305391ef14c5a1db60e]
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  ? nvkm_vmm_iter.constprop.0+0x2a5/0x890 [nouveau b94536815bcbee6c07bf0305391ef14c5a1db60e]
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  ? nvkm_vmm_ptes_sparse+0x1e0/0x1e0 [nouveau b94536815bcbee6c07bf0305391ef14c5a1db60e]
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  nvkm_vmm_put_locked+0x109/0x280 [nouveau b94536815bcbee6c07bf0305391ef14c5a1db60e]
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  ? nvkm_vmm_ptes_sparse+0x1e0/0x1e0 [nouveau b94536815bcbee6c07bf0305391ef14c5a1db60e]
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  nvkm_uvmm_mthd+0x686/0x6b0 [nouveau b94536815bcbee6c07bf0305391ef14c5a1db60e]
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  nvkm_ioctl+0xd9/0x180 [nouveau b94536815bcbee6c07bf0305391ef14c5a1db60e]
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  nvif_object_mthd+0xcc/0x200 [nouveau b94536815bcbee6c07bf0305391ef14c5a1db60e]
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  nvif_vmm_put+0x64/0x80 [nouveau b94536815bcbee6c07bf0305391ef14c5a1db60e]
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  nouveau_vma_del+0x80/0xd0 [nouveau b94536815bcbee6c07bf0305391ef14c5a1db60e]
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  nouveau_gem_object_close+0x1eb/0x220 [nouveau b94536815bcbee6c07bf0305391ef14c5a1db60e]
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  drm_gem_handle_delete+0x6a/0xd0
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  ? drm_mode_destroy_dumb+0x40/0x40
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  drm_ioctl_kernel+0xca/0x170
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  drm_ioctl+0x1eb/0x450
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  ? drm_mode_destroy_dumb+0x40/0x40
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  nouveau_drm_ioctl+0x5a/0xb0 [nouveau b94536815bcbee6c07bf0305391ef14c5a1db60e]
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  __x64_sys_ioctl+0x91/0xd0
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  do_syscall_64+0x5c/0x90
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x1b/0x40
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  ? do_syscall_64+0x6b/0x90
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x145/0x1d0
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x1b/0x40
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  ? do_syscall_64+0x6b/0x90
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  ? exc_page_fault+0x74/0x170
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x63/0xcd
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7f6a3df23c0f
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: Code: 00 48 89 44 24 18 31 c0 48 8d 44 24 60 c7 04 24 10 00 00 00 48 89 44 24 08 48 8d 44 24 20 48 89 44 24 10 b8 10 00 00 00 0f 05 <89> c2 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 18 48 8b 44 24 18 64 48 2b 04 25 28 00 00
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffcd9c547d0 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000561a976c48d0 RCX: 00007f6a3df23c0f
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: RDX: 00007ffcd9c54864 RSI: 00000000c00464b4 RDI: 0000000000000015
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: RBP: 00007ffcd9c54864 R08: 0000561a976da840 R09: 00007f6a3e0857a0
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: R10: 0000000000000050 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00000000c00464b4
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel: R13: 0000000000000015 R14: 0000561a96eef7a0 R15: 00007f6a3d4c8a60
Mai 10 14:47:34 user1-victus kernel:  </TASK>
Ma
```

Comment: You're still using `nouveau`. Maybe start with black listing it.

Comment: could it be that lightdm uses nouveau and nvidia is loaded later? How do I blacklist it?

Comment: LightDM does not choose or load graphics drivers. https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+blacklist+nouveau%3F Why on Earth are you using Linux if you actively refuse to do the basic research of the simplest of questions? Actually you somehow incorrectly installed NVIDIA drivers as well, which indicates you actively avoided properly installing them using your distro guidelines. Here: https://www.google.com/search?q=MANJARO+install+nvidia+drivers The first Google result: https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Configure_NVIDIA_(non-free)_settings_and_load_them_on_Startup I'm horrified.

Comment: Linux is not fun, it's a lot of work, debugging and researching. If you are not OK with that, Windows could be a nice option.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov please don't scare our contemporaries :) Honestly, I booted into my Windows laptop once and had to debug Windows BitDefender for half an hour before I could use my Laptop. Windows is not universally the easier choice, unless you insist on using niche Linux distros, with a few exceptions: effing **Nvidia** drivers being that exception.

Comment: @user2741831 don't worry, "how to blacklist nouveau" is usually not very hard (often not even necessary).

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out. I did a clean install of Manjaro i3 on sn older computer and set up drm just like before and it worked just fine. Must be nvidia drivers. They seem to be wonky in general. They sometimes load games, sometimes not.

Comment: NVIDIA drivers work nearly flawlessly if they are installed properly. At least it's been the case for me for the past 20+ years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have finally figured it out. At least autorandr now finally detects the plugging in of an external screen, which is the main reason I wanted to enable drm.

I followed the following article
https://vfbsilva.medium.com/howto-set-up-prime-with-nvidia-proprietary-driver-c647e3597447

Step 1: uninstall bumblebee

Step 2: change /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-mhwd.conf to:

```
 Section "Module"
    Load "modesetting"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1:0:0"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
EndSection
```

Step 3 change /etc/modprobe.d/mhwd-gpu.conf to

```
##
## Generated by mhwd - Manjaro Hardware Detection
##
 
blacklist nouveau
#blacklist ttm
#blacklist drm_kms_helper
#blacklist drm
options nvidia "NVreg_DynamicPowerManagement=0x02"


blacklist nvidiafb
blacklist rivafb
options nvidia_drm modeset=1
```

Step 4

create this file (/usr/local/bin/optimus.sh)

```
#!/bin/sh

xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0
xrandr --auto
```

make it executable

```
chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/optimus.sh
```

Edit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf and set (if you are using another dm check the article)

```
display-setup-script=/usr/local/bin/optimus
```